# Selecting Columns after joining two tables

Tags: sql

I am trying to select 'contractkey' after joining the two tables. All I can run now is "select *" and then all columns are returned. Below is the query. It runs perfectly as long as I do not try to select a column. How can I select a specific column? do I need to to label the table after the INNER JOIN?

```
Select * 
FROM 
(SELECT
    attachmentdata.contractkey,
    requirementinfo.reqcode,
    requirementinfo.parentidkey as 'ReqInfoParentID',
    max(attachment.datecreated) as datecreated,
    applicationinfo.hocompletiondate

FROM  location1.attachment

LEFT JOIN location1.attachmentdata
    on  attachment.contractkey = attachmentdata.contractkey
    and attachment.id = attachmentdata.parentidkey --Links Attachment Type

LEFT JOIN location1.requirementinfo
    on  attachment.contractkey = requirementinfo.contractkey
    and attachment.parentidkey = requirementinfo.id --Links Attachment Type

INNER JOIN location1.applicationinfo
    on  attachment.contractkey = applicationinfo.contractkey
    and requirementinfo.parentidkey = applicationinfo.parentidkey --Links Policy Type

where
    (requirementinfo.reqcode = 2) 

group by attachmentdata.contractkey,requirementinfo.reqcode, 
requirementinfo.parentidkey, applicationinfo.hocompletiondate) as table1

INNER JOIN

(SELECT
    attachmentdata.contractkey,
    requirementinfo.reqcode,
    requirementinfo.parentidkey as 'ReqInfoParentID',
    attachment.datecreated,
    applicationinfo.hocompletiondate,
    attachmentdata.pcdata

FROM  location1.attachment

LEFT JOIN location1.attachmentdata
    on  attachment.contractkey = attachmentdata.contractkey
    and attachment.id = attachmentdata.parentidkey --Links Attachment Type

LEFT JOIN location1.requirementinfo
    on  attachment.contractkey = requirementinfo.contractkey
    and attachment.parentidkey = requirementinfo.id --Links Attachment Type

INNER JOIN location1.applicationinfo
    on  attachment.contractkey = applicationinfo.contractkey
    and requirementinfo.parentidkey = applicationinfo.parentidkey)table2

on table1.contractkey = table2.contractkey
and table1.reqcode = table2.reqcode
and table1.ReqInfoParentID = table2.ReqInfoParentID
and table1.datecreated = table2.datecreated
and table1.hocompletiondate = table2.hocompletiondate
```

Comment: Please edit your question and tell us _how_ things fail. Maybe you have duplicate column names between the two tables. Then you will need to specify the table you want the column from : `select table1.foo from (...)`

Comment: Yes. That was it. The columns we duplicating!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are columns `contractkey` in both tables, so the system doesn't know which ones you want.  So you will have to put tablename in front of it.

`SELECT table1.contractkey, ...`

Comment: How can I add at table name in front of it?

Comment: You alias your two queries with `table1` and `table2`.  So that's what you use to differentiate between `table1.contractkey` and `table2.contractkey`.

Answer (score 0):

Add the following to the end of your outermost inner table selects:

```
SELECT contractkey FROM
(SELECT
    attachmentdata.contractkey,

          etc...

) AS t(contractkey,reqcode,ReqInfoParentID,datecreated,hocompletiondate)
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not required to "Label the table"(Alias). Use Case to make sure it won't put null for records that are not in the AttachmentData table as follow:

```
Select *  FROM 
(SELECT case 
   WHEN attachmentdata.contractkey IS NOT NULL THEN attachmentdata.contractkey 
   else attachment.contractkey END AS contractkey,

    requirementinfo.reqcode,
    requirementinfo.parentidkey as 'ReqInfoParentID',
    max(attachment.datecreated) as datecreated,
    applicationinfo.hocompletiondat
    ...
```

Comment: Do you even know the OP's problem?